# How to transform XHTML+CSS with embedded images to XSL-FO?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, html-to-pdf, css-to-pdf

I'm trying to transform a simple HTML page to XSL-FO, to feed into Apache FOP for PDF rendering.
The steps are: HTML+CSS -> XHTML -> XSL-FO -> PDF.

I've used the java library [CSSToXSLFO](http://www.re.be/css2xslfo/index.xhtml) to transform XHTML to XSL-FO. This works, however it's incapable of handling embedded images.

Are there any tools to transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 style="color: green">Hello world!</h1>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...=" />
  </body>
</html>
```

into

```
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block>
        <fo:block color="green">Hello world!</fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic src="url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...=)" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit" scaling="uniform"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
```

?

Comment: You state it is incapable of handling base64 encoded images yet and example exists http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.Images so we need  more info. Perhaps your image is to large?

Answer (score 0):

If the FOP processor supports data URIs in `fo:external-graphic` you can of course use XSLT to transform XHTML to XSL-FO with e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="sample">
                <fo:region-body/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="sample">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body"/>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="body">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:block>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="h1">
      <fo:block>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="img">
      <fo:external-graphic src="{@src}" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit" scaling="uniform"/>    
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That is a minimal example to handle the `h1` and the `img` element, I haven't tried to spell out any HTML CSS `style` attribute to XSL-FO presentational attribute transformation but you can of course use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>` instead of `<xsl:apply-templates/>` and then add templates to transform e.g. `style="color: green"` to `color="green"`. As CSS has its own, non-XML syntax, obviously writing a full parser for arbitrary style attributes is a demanding task beyond the scope of StackOverflow answers.

I am also not quite sure about the allowed src attribute syntax in XSL-FO, FOP seems to understand the direct `src="{@src}"` just fine, but of course, to create the format you indicated in your question, you could as well use `src="url({@src})"`.